# Dative case vs. "für" + accusative case

Tags: meaning

> Mathe ist meinen Ausbildern wichtig.
>   Mathe ist für meine Ausbilder wichtig.

Do the two sentences have the same meaning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your quoted example sentence, both expressions are nearly equal, but:

> wichtig sein für jemanden/etwas

means something is important for/to something/someone and

> jemandem wichtig sein

means something *is considered important* by someone

The difference becomes apparent when you use the verbs on something that doesn't normally *consider* things, like: You can say

> Frisches Heu, Wasser und viel Auslauf sind wichtig für ein Pferd.

but rather not

> <s>Dem Pferd sind Frisches Heu, Wasser und Auslauf wichtig.</s>

(because you wouldn't imply an opinion on healthy living with a horse)

Comment: The sad horse has no name.

Comment: @Janka But it's out of the rain.

Comment: however, a desert is not the best place for a horse, either

Answer (score 1):

The sentences carry in fact different meanings, but more on a subtle leevel. Both indicate that math is important for my educators or trainers. But there is a slight difference in which way it is important to them.

> Mathe ist meinen Ausbildern wichtig.

In german **jemandem wichtig sein** expresses that it is important **to** someone and can even be understood as being dear to someone's heart.

> Mathe ist für meine Ausbilder wichtig.

This rather means it is important **for** them and expresses more an opinion they hold within themelves.

The only context provided is that they are educators and specifically that they are yours. So it is somehow implied that they might also consider math as important for you or that math is very important in education generally, but it is not specifically expressed.

If you replace **Mathe** with another expression the difference becomes more clear.

> Gesunde Ernährung ist meinen Ausbildern wichtig.

My educators care about healthy nutrition.

> Gesunde Ernährung ist für meine Ausbilder wichtig.

Healthy nutrition is important for my educators.

Answer (score -1):

Not identical:

```
Mathe ist meinen Ausbildern wichtig
```

means that they see this topic as important (for you, or for somebody or anybody else)

```
Mathe ist für meine Ausbilder wichtig
```

means that it is important **for themselves**.
Although you might find quite some people using both versions having both meanings, especially in spoken German.

BTW, it's *Ausbilder*, without the "n"...

Comment: Das n habe ich hineineditiert und dann wieder entfernt. Beide Versionen existieren und sind korrekt, aber der Ausbild**n**er scheint eher in Österreich daheim zu sein und dürfte in Deutschland unbekannt sein. Als ich das bemerkt habe, habe ich wieder die ursprüngliche Schreibweise des Fragestellers wiederhergestellt.

Comment: -1 für die Aussage, die beiden Sätze würden eine unterschiedliche Bedeutung haben. Tatsächlich erwähnt keiner der beiden Sätzen den Auszubildenden, daher kann sich auch keiner auf ihn beziehen. Beide Sätze sprechen nur vom Ausbilder, und davon, dass ihm etwas wichtig ist. Darüber, warum ihm Mathe wichtig ist, wird nichts ausgesagt.

Comment: Dadurch, dass von "meinen" die Rede ist, ist der Auszubildende m. E. sehr wohl erwähnt, wen  auch indirekt. Wenn ich von "meinem" Ausbilder schreibe, muss ich ja wohl der Auszubildende sein

Comment: Zudem habe ich auch nicht direkt von Auszubildenden geschrieben, sondern dass es den Ausbildern insgesamt wichtig ist, also für irgendwelche Auszubildende allgemein, siehe auch die Antwort von @tofro,die zugegeben die Sache etwas besser beschreibt als meine

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Also ich würde auch einen Unterschied zwischen den Sätzen sehen. Der erste Satz sagt, dass ihnen Mathematik am Herzen liegt, der zweite, dass sie Mathematik benötigen.

Answer (score -1):

> Mathe ist **meinen Ausbildern** wichtig.

In the first sentence the object is an dative object. The kind of syntactic usage of dative case in this special sentence is called *dativus commodi*. When an object stands in *dativus commodi* in a German sentence, then it is the beneficiary or aggrieved party of the action.

Neither dative case nor any similar syntactic construction exists in English.

This sentence means:

> Math is important **to my trainers.**

So, as you can see, in Englisch you have to add a preposition (*to*) that doesn't exist in the German sentence.

But you can do this in German too:

---

> Mathe ist **für meine Ausbilder** wichtig.

This is the exact equivalent of

> Math is important **to my trainers.**

(just in a different word order)

The part *für meine Ausbilder* (also the english part *to my trainers*) is called a prepositional object, because it starts with a preposition. Note, that this prepositional object does not stand in any of the four German cases. But it consists of two inner parts, and one of them is in a grammatical case:

- **für**
  This part is a preposition. In this construction it is equivalent to the English preposition *to*. (In many other constructions you better translate *für = for*.)
- **meine Ausbilder**
  This part is an accusative object, because the preposition *für* needs its reference in this case.

---

So, both German sentences translate into the same English sentence. (You can also say, that there are two possible German translations for the English sentence.) From this you can read, that both German sentences mean the same.